# 405 Method Not Allowed with AngularJS + RESTful + Java

Tags: java, angularjs, rest

I get the following error when I try to call a java restful service from angularjs:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/test/info/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

This is the angularjs code

```
...    
$http.defaults.headers.common['content-type'] = 'application/json'; 
$http.defaults.headers.common['content-type'] = 'application/json';   
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + authdata; 

var userdata = { username: 'test', password: '123456' };    

$http({ method: 'POST', url: '/test/info', data : userdata })
    .success(function (userdataResponse) { 
        $rootScope.userData = userdataResponse;        
   });
...
```

And this is the java code

```
@POST
@Path("/test/info")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response getDataUserInformation(Userdata request){
    Userdata user = userService.findByUser(request.getUser());
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    DataUserDTO dataUserDTO = dataUserService.findByID(user.getID());
    return Response.ok().entity(gson.toJson(DataUserDTO).toString()).build();
}
```

What's the problem? I have a same function for the login and works well but this not...

Thanks for your help

Comment: How are you deserializing that JSON?

Comment: It's not necessary because it's specified in the headers

Comment: I was referring to the Java side of it.  You're deserializing that JSON into a bean of type `Userdata`, aren't you?  How do you deserialize it?  Is there something going wrong with the deserialization process?

Comment: Java side was ok (Gson library deserialize the json info). I changed the method "POST" to "GET" (on both sides), and just send the username, and now works... Thank you

Comment: Is this the only resource that's giving you problems? What about others?

Comment: I guess "method:'POST'" statement is not recognised. I used similar code in my project and it did "GET" instead of "POST". Then I changed the code to `setRequestMethod`instead of using `setRequestProperty`. Issue got fixed :).

Answer (score -1):

Is it working with the following? The .json might be needed.

```
$http({ method: 'POST', url: '/test/info.json', data : userdata })
    .success(function (userdataResponse) { 
        $rootScope.userData = userdataResponse;        
   });
```